# Jquery Find if number is in between two numbers when using an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to find if a certain number is in between two other numbers.

I have an array of 'Bands' and their 'Color' codes.

What I want is, if the 'co2Amount' is in between one of the array 'Band' values, then it displays that bands 'Color' code.

So the code below should output '#c8ff5c' as its the color code for any co2 amount between 101 and 200.

Heres what I have:

```js
var co2Bands = [ {Band:"0-100",Color:"#deff9e" }, {Band:"101-200",Color:"#c8ff5c"}, ]; 

var co2Amount = "150";

$.each(co2Bands, function() { 
var bandNumber = this.Band.split('-');
if (bandNumber[0] >= co2Amount && bandNumber[1] <= co2Amount) {
$('#co2ColorCode').append(this.Color+'<br>'); 
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="co2ColorCode"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have control of the object in the `co2Bands` array? If so I'd suggest splitting `Band` in to two separate integers, min and max

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- You need to convert the splits to number:

  ```
  this.Band.split('-').map(Number)
  ```
- `co2Amount` should be a number too, not a string
- your two conditions are both testing the wrong thing

```js
var co2Bands = [ {Band:"0-100",Color:"#deff9e" }, {Band:"101-200",Color:"#c8ff5c"}, ]; 

var co2Amount = 150;

$.each(co2Bands, function() { 
  var bandNumber = this.Band.split('-').map(Number);
  if (bandNumber[0] <= co2Amount && co2Amount <= bandNumber[1]) {
    $('#co2ColorCode').append(this.Color+'<br>'); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="co2ColorCode"></div>
```

Comment: See other problems I have added to the answer. The snippet shows the color now.

Comment: you can use parseInt also to convert the string to number